# Extracting a part of string in java

Tags: java

**I am having the following data in a text file:**

```
 proc sort data=oneplan.cust_duplicates(dbindex=yes) out=mibatch.cust_duplicates;
    from oneplan.fsa_authorised_agencies (dbindex=yes) 
    set oneplan.fsa_agency_permissions(where=(regulated_activity in ('103','106','107','108')));
    set oneplan.customer_flags(where=(flag_id in(54,14,34)));
    from oneplan.document_history (dbindex=yes) 
    set oneplan.product_references;
  proc sort data=oneplan.fast_track_log(where=(upcase(business_entry)="INCOME VERIFICATION FAST TRACKED"))   out=fast_track_log;
    set oneplan.product_characteristics(rename=(value=filler)where=(characteristic_type="OFFS" ));
    set oneplan.mtg_offset_benefits (where=(modified_date between &extractdate and &batchcutoff) 
      from oneplan.mtg_payment_options a;
    from oneplan.acc_retention_risk acr;
    from oneplan.acc_retention_risk_hist acr;
    from oneplan.account_repay_veh rv;
    from oneplan.repay_vehicle_map rvm;
    from oneplan.frozen_accounts as fa left join mibatch.accounts as a
```

Now i need to fetch the part from each line which starts with `oneplan.` and ends with a space.

Also if the line has two `oneplan.` then each must be extracted separately.

Example:  `agtut oneplan.m htyutu oneplan.j hgyut`

i need the output as: `oneplan.m` and `oneplan.j`

kindly give me suggestions in doing this please...

Comment: Is this homework? Should have a homework tag if so.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex like:

```
String text = ....
String regex = "(oneplan\\.\\w)\\w+\\s+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Will print the results:

```
oneplan.f
oneplan.d
oneplan.m
oneplan.m
oneplan.a
oneplan.a
oneplan.a
oneplan.r
oneplan.f
```

If you instead want the entire word you can use `matcher.group()` in combination with the regex:

```
"oneplan\\.\\w+\\s+"
```

Comment: And, take a look at this post if you'd like to know how to use regex : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291102/extracting-a-part-of-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [BufferedReader#readLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and [String#startsWith](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) String#endsWith.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the various `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` methods.